# In Chrome moving the element while handling its mousedown event prevents the click event from firing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

I want to move an element to the "top" when it is clicked on. However if I move the element in my `mousedown` handler (making it the last child of its parent) then my `click` event handler is never called, although the `mouseup` event handler is. This missing `click` event happens on Chrome but not on Firefox.

If I don't move the element in the `mousedown` handler then Chrome does call the `click` handler the same as Firefox.

I need the `click` event to be called. **My question is** can I do something different to still move the element on `mousedown` and get the `click` event after `mouseup`? Is this a Chrome bug, or a grey area in the way events on elements are defined to be processed by the spec (I'm not sure which spec applies here).

(Actually I want to move it to the top while dragging and move it back afterwards, but this problem can be illustrated in a simpler way with just mouseup and mousedown).

I encountered this manipulating svg shapes so that is how I've structured my example.

What you see in the console when you click on the top left circle displayed by the below example is:

Chrome console output:

```
circle1 MouseDown event handler called
circle1 MouseUp event handler called
```

Firefox console output:

```
"circle1 MouseDown event handler called" clicked_event_test.xhtml:31:8
"circle1 MouseUp event handler called" clicked_event_test.xhtml:38:8
"circle1 Click event handler called" clicked_event_test.xhtml:43:8
```

**Notice that the click handler was called by Firefox but not by Chrome.**

Sample code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <title>clicked event test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:#eee; width:300px; height:200px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 200px;">
        <g fill="blue" stroke="red">
            <g id="circle1" class="sketch-shape draggable" transform="translate(10,10)">
                <circle fill="orange" opacity="0.8" stroke-width="1px" cx="30" cy="30" r="30"></circle>
            </g>
            <g id="polygon1" class="sketch-shape draggable" transform="translate(20,20)">
                <polygon stroke-width="1px" points="0,85 0,50 132,0 264,50 264,85 222,155 42,155"></polygon>
            </g>
            <g id="circle2" class="sketch-shape draggable" transform="translate(230,130)">
                <circle fill="yellow" opacity="0.8" stroke-width="1px" cx="30" cy="30" r="30"></circle>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<script>
//<![CDATA[

    var handleMouseDown = function handleMouseDown(name, event)
    {
        window.console.log(name +' MouseDown event handler called');
        var elem = event.currentTarget;
        elem.parentNode.appendChild(elem);
    };

    var handleMouseUp = function handleMouseUp(name, event)
    {
        window.console.log(name + ' MouseUp event handler called');
    };

    var handleClick = function handleClick(name, event)
    {
        window.console.log(name + ' Click event handler called');
    };

    var handleDoubleClick = function handleDoubleClick(name, event)
    {
        window.console.log(name + ' DoubleClick event handler called');
    };

    var attachHandlers = function attachHandlers(name, element)
    {
        element.onmousedown = handleMouseDown.bind(element, name);
        element.onmouseup = handleMouseUp.bind(element, name);
        element.onclick = handleClick.bind(element, name);
        element.ondblclick = handleDoubleClick.bind(element, name);
    };

    [ 'circle1', 'circle2', 'polygon1' ]
        .forEach(function (name)
            {
                var element = document.getElementById(name);
                attachHandlers(name, element);
            });
//]]>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought a "click" was defined as a mousedown followed quickly by a mouseup in the same place. If the mouse moves, its not a click.

Comment: That may be true, but notice that this example doesn't move the mouse between the mousedown and mouseup, and the click still happens in firefox and doesn't happen in chrome.